# Filter table contents by year

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am having problem with filtering table contents by year.

Table field name : Startdate

Type : varchar

Eg. of startdate: 20170427 1600 ie.`date("Ymd Hi")`

Am retrieving whole past contents from table using this condition  `Status=1 AND Startdate < '" . date("Ymd Hi") . "'"`

I need to retrieve table contents by year. How can i write the sql statement?

Would appreciate if anybody can help me on this.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Update the table to change stratdate format  to datetime

Answer (score 0):

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select str_to_date('20170427 1600','%Y%m%d %H%i');
+--------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('20170427 1600','%Y%m%d %H%i') |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 2017-04-27 16:00:00                        |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Assumes your string is a properly formed

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select str_to_date('2017427 16','%Y%m%d %H%i');
```

fails

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2017427 16','%Y%m%d %H%i') |
+-----------------------------------------+
| NULL                                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```